# Using select statement to find how many IPs came back today

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, mysqli

I have a select statement that tries to find how many ip came back today, that also visited this month, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT ip, COUNT( ip ) AS matches, DATE AS tempDate
FROM ipAll
WHERE YEAR( DATE ) =  '2015'
AND MONTH( DATE ) =  '12'
GROUP BY ip
HAVING matches > 1
AND tempDate =  '2015-12-29'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Expected Result:**

For it to return one or more rows.

**Actual Result:**

It returned 0 rows

**Note:**

date is a column name, and yes, I am sure that there 2 or more ips in the database in the same year, month and day.

Comment: I would try this : ` select ip, count(*) as matches, DATE as tempDate from ipAll WHERE YEAR(DATE)=2015 and MONTH(DATE)=12 GROUP BY ip HAVING matches > 1 LIMIT 0, 30`

Answer (score -1):

Perfectly works for me:

```
SELECT ip, COUNT( ip ) AS matches, DATE AS tempDate
FROM ipAll
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m')
GROUP BY ip HAVING matches > 1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

NOTE that DATE column is a [MySQL Keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) you should replace the column name with a different one